# Convert ambigious date string to unix timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

if you have an ambiguous date like "05/04/2014" (which is dd/mm/yyyy but just by looking at it could be month first too), how can you convert it to a PHP unix timestamp?

It looks like https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php is close to what I want, but there is no way to specify the date format as being day first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xdazz's answer is almost correct, but you will absorb the current time if you do that without removing it explicitly.

```
<?
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", "05/04/2014");
$dt->setTime(0,0,0); # remove current time.
echo $dt->getTimestamp();
?>
```

In understand why we need line 2, replace line 3 with

```
  var_dump($dt);
```

Then, delete line 2, and observe that there is a time in addition to the desired date.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "absorb the current time"? I don't understand why you are doing setTime() afterwards. Thanks

Comment: @b85411, It means that your timestamp will be `05/04/2014` + the number of seconds since the beginning of **today** on the clock in your current system.

Comment: By current system - do you mean the server running the script? Surely PHP isn't able to determine local system time? Thanks

Comment: @b85411, My tests seem to show that it is UTC, but I am not 100% sure about that. But yes, it would be getting the actual time from the server running the script.

Answer (score 0):

you can use PHP fucntion **date_format**:

```
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
echo date_format($date, 'm-d-Y H:i:s');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 0):

See **[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)** and **[DateTime::getTimestamp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)**:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '05/04/2014');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```